# Gitlab module.exports matching routes issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, gitlab, module.exports

I am writing a script to add to a certain webpage with use of Gitlab and module.exports for the page. I have my page setup as follows:

```
 module.exports = {
  name: "My script",
  description: "Do something on a page",
  maintainer: "Myself",
  
  routes: [
    {
    match: /something\\.atlassian\\.net\/browse\/\w+-\d+/, action: init
    },
         ],

}
```

No matter which way i change the regex, double slashes and checking on regex101, it doesnt match the page. It is a jira page and im wondering if i need to match another url in the background? The url i am tyring to run on is:

https://something.atlassian.net/browse/pp-000000

Thanks for any help.